# Plugin-driven Application Design with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plugins, architecture, client-side

I’m searching for a way to develop a website that consists of several plug-ins. The website itself is basically only a container for the plug-ins. My scenario:

A user logs into the application and is forwarded to a dashboard, where he sees all apps that are available to him. An app is a small tool for a specific use case (e.g. cancelling an order or searching for a customer profile). When he clicks on an app, it is opened in the main view of the page (a small app-independent navbar will always be visible so that the user can change apps and go back to the dashboard quickly).

Key features:

- The website consists of small, *independent* plug-ins
- The available plug-ins depend on the user (e.g. an admin has more plug-ins)
- Standalone plug-in development would be beneficial

The server will be written in C#, whereas the client and all the plug-ins should be written in JS, especially AngularJS. If anyone has done something like this before or knows libraries to realize this, I would appreciate a hint in the right direction

Comment: For the client-side modularity you can take a look at [angular-require-lazy](https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy). It is by no means a solution to your problem, but it may help, especially the module discovery parts.

Comment: you could have multiple distinct angular apps under the same domain e.g. my-portal/app1, my-portal/app2. Then you can use local storage or cookies to share data between these apps.